# React - return component onClick event

Tags: reactjs

Can I create a new component on a `onClick`-event in `reactjs`.
I've tried this:

My component where the click event occurs:

```
...
<li onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit entry</li>
...
```

This is the `edit` method:

```
 edit(event) {
        return <CreateFreightEntryModal key={"freightEditModal" + this.state.freight.ID} openOnStartup="true" modalId={"freightEditModal" + this.state.freight.ID} />
    }
```

No error is thrown, but the component is not being created. Doing I something wrong or is this not really recommended?

Comment: The onlick function is not editing the state at all, you're just returning a component. You should have the edit function toggle an 'edit' state that causes the `CreateFreightEntryModal` component to be rendered instead of whatever is normally there.

Comment: where you are expecting that returned element will get rendered? use a state bool and onclick of edit button use `setState` and update that with true, use that variable to render the Component, Check the [Conditional Rendering part of Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: If this is just 1 element, keep a flag in state and use `{ flag ? component : null}` in render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react, showing a modal is a bit tricky because of it's nature.

```
edit() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true })
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
             { this.state.showModal && <CreateFreightEntryModal props/> }
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this solution already, but I have a list of more than 600 entries. I don't want to create for each entry of this list an own component. My thought was to create a component, when an entry is clicked. It saves much loading time not to create foreach entry an own component. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok. Now I understand your way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> You'd better render component with state as @Ozgur GUL stated in the
>   answer.

However, if you have to render something dynamically, you can do like this.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

...
edit() {
  ReactDOM.render(<CreateFreightEntryModal key={"freightEditModal" + this.state.freight.ID} openOnStartup="true" modalId={"freightEditModal" + this.state.freight.ID} />);
}
```